# Write a JavaScript function that changes behavior based on optional arguments

Tags: javascript, function

I want to write a function that takes an optional argument and changes its behavior depending on whether or not that argument is provided. This is the first way I thought to do this:

```
function foo(optionalArg) {
    if (optionalArg) {
        // do something with the optionalArg
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do this, or is there a safer/better way?

**EDIT:** If you actually *read* the question, you'll notice that it's different than the "duplicates" some claim this is. I *know* how to provide default values to a function's arguments; I found those links when I was trying to figure this out on my own first. *But I'm not looking for how to do that.* I'm looking for the best way to change my function's behavior based on whether or not the argument was provided.

Comment: @Juhana that doesn't change behavior, it provides defaults for optional arguments.

Comment: @Juhana This isn't a duplicate. Those other posts don't answer my question. There is a difference.

Comment: @nicael This isn't a duplicate. Those other posts don't answer my question. There is a difference.

Comment: @torazaburo This isn't a duplicate. Those other posts don't answer my question. There is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing is it fine, but here's a few tips.

1) In ES6 you could have a [default argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) in case one is not supplied:

```
function foo(optionalArg = 'something cool') {
   // have your function go about its business as usual
}
```

2) Same as above, except not using ES6:

```
function foo(optionalArg) {
   if (optionalArg === undefined) {
      optionalArg = 'something cool'
   }
   // have your function go about its business as usual
}
```

3) Check your argument against undefined to avoid false positives:

```
function foo(optionalArg) {
    if (optionalArg !== undefined) {
        // do something with the optionalArg
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
}
```

4) Place the longer block in the else statement for optimal readability:

```
function foo(optionalArg) {
   if (optionalArg !== undefined) {
     // do something with the optionalArg
   } else {
     // do something different
     // big
     // huge
     // grandiose
     // epic
   }
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome, helps a ton, thanks so much. This wasn't answered by the other posts some people claim this is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

Specificity is often better and arguments that were declared but not provided are undefined, so you could do:

```
function foo(optionalArg) {
    if (optionalArg !== undefined) {
        // do something with the optionalArg
    } else {
        // do something different
    }
}
```

Using `if (optionalArg)` will treat falsy values (`0`, `''`, etc) as if they were omitted entirely, which is probably not what you want.

This method will still return a false negative if the argument was explicitly set to `undefined` (as t.niese mentioned in the comments), which is rare but possible. You could check `arguments.length` to work around that, but `arguments` is not available in ES6 arrow functions. For ES5, using:

```
if (arguments.length > 0) { ...
```

ought to do the trick, otherwise you can use:

```
function foo(...args) {
  if (args.length > 0) { ...
```

and collect your own array, which *will* work in arrow functions:

```
(...args) => {
  if (args.length > 0) { ...
```

Comment: This would obfuscate that case when value passed as argument is `undefined`. Testing against `arguments.length` is a better way to determin how many arguments are passed.

Comment: Checking `arguments` is not always available, especially not in ES6 arrow functions. I am adding an example using an equivalent array that will work across the board.

Comment: Awesome, great examples. Thanks so much. This wasn't answered by the other posts some people claim this is a duplicate of.